# How do these hex values become this?

Tags: hex

I am pretty stumped on a few hex values that become these values. I've been playing around with the values for a bit and I can't figure it out. Perhaps someone here can give me a clue as to how these values show up as hex or vise versa. When I got these values they were in reverse order hex. I ordered them from left to right to make things simpler (I am 99% sure these values should be reverse order since other values I got were reverse order).

- 6C C4 F0 00 should become 1/1/2000 in Date/Time format.
- 6C C4 F0 38 should also be 1/1/2000 but I am not sure how this is the case.
- FF FF FE 38 should be -2.
- 00 FF FF FF should be 0.
- FF 00 00 00 should be -1.

If anyone can help me out with this, I would humbly appreciate it! Thank you!

The raw data:

00F0C46C38F0C46C38FEFFFFFFFDFFFF

The raw data is in reverse order hex in sets of 4 bytes.

- 00F0C46C, should be a date/time format of 1/1/2000
- 38F0C46C, should be a date/time format of 1/1/2000
- 38FEFFFF, should be -2
- FFFDFFFF, should be -3

I know the structure is correct because the program is working and creating a table correctly, there are just some values in each column that are handled differently.

Thank you!

Comment: This is mighty confusing; do you have additional context for this problem? A homework statement, or some source / protocol that you're trying to reverse engineer?

Comment: Give to us a *raw* data (without any ordering) and task description. May be you just made a wrong ordering.

Comment: According to my experience, not all hex values may represent a **Value**. For example, each 4-th byte can represent a some kind of **validity flag**, or can be even a **CRC code**. Can you give the name of the program, which protocol you trying to reverse? Can you give such data (if it is possible): retrieve from program several byte sequences describing the same parameters. So I can compare it and at least make some guesses.

Comment: I mean, if you have **ParameterA** which changes slightly, could you, please, make a several repetitive measurement of the parameter? It could be helpful for determining at least if all bytes are valuable.

Comment: The program was made by me. I don't mind giving you the source code for it but I don't suspect it will help. I did consider the 4 byte value to be validity flags but I don't know how it starts. I tried simple math and using flanking numbers to determine specific values but I just couldn't figure it out. I can give you the file which I am trying to convert and the source code for my program to show you what I am talking about.

Comment: Looking at the hex patterns above, I can agree that there are some flags in there. Negative values should have a flanking FF in front of it, but how are the values for that determined?

Comment: I'm confused. If this is your program, why do you want to reverse a  protocol? Hm... I assume, the protocol is not yours, right? Are you using a third party component?

Comment: "I can give you the file which I am trying to convert and the source code for my program to show you what I am talking about". Yeah, it can be helpful...

Comment: It's a document that has been compressed. It was a table but it was made by someone else. I have the table decompressed (somewhat older version) and just want to see the newer version (in this compressed file). So I have to reverse this protocol to pull out the data. I pretty much got all of them out but some values are just in a special format like the ones I posted above. There are no third party programs involved for this except the program I made to read it. It is written in python. Can you give me an e-mail so I can send you the data and source code? Hopefully you can explain how it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your byte order wrong. The first byte seems to be dead space or otherwise occupied, and I'm betting you left `FF` off the end of what you showed us.

Split into words:

```
00  F0C46C38 F0C46C38 FEFFFFFF FDFFFF
```

Now, reverse the byte order on the first two words and you get:

```
0x386CC4F0 = 946652400
```

Which is

```
$ date -ur 946652400
Fri Dec 31 15:00:00 UTC 1999
```

So midnight 1/1/2000 in the [UTC+9 time zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC+9). Too close to be a coincidence, I'm guessing you or wherever you got that data from is in that time zone.

Now, the next two words in proper byte order:

```
FFFFFFFE
FFFFFFFD
```

Guess what? [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation of -2 and -3.

Comment: +1 You are exactly right. I have already done with this... but you are a quick one :)

Comment: The data is from Seoul. Remarkable. Let me look over this to make sure! Thank you! :)

Comment: Holy moley! Just looked at the Data Inspector in Hex Workshop and you are exactly right. I was scratching my head wondering why the heck the number was off. I was researching the date/time and thought negative numbers were handled specially. Finally discovered whats wrong. For some reason the original author added a FF in front of one of the values. Throws everything off. Crazy, thank you again!